# I do not completely understand the intuition behind equivalent sources used in source transformations

Tags: voltage-divider, current-source, thevenin, source, norton

My book states that two circuits can be considered equivalent if they produce the same voltage and current in any resistor connected to the two ends of the circuit.  The book then goes about proving how various different circuits are interchangeable because they produce the same voltage and current in a resistor with arbitrary resistance connected to the two ends of said circuit.  However, what is bothering me is that this strategy seems to assume that the rest of the circuit can be reduced to a single resistor.  But clearly this strategy is used when the rest of the circuit cannot be reduced to a single resistor (such as when the rest of the circuit has a voltage or current source).  Could someone please explain to me why this strategy is still valid in said situation?

Answer (score 1):

There is an unstated assumption that the circuit is ***linear***. It's easy to devise a nonlinear circuit that would look the same to any real value of resistor but fail when certain voltage sources were connected. Think of a series battery + resistor with a reverse-biased diode across the terminals.

Since the circuit is linear, the [superposition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_theorem) applies. That (and the uniqueness theorem) is adequate to prove [Thevenin's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9venin's_theorem). It also applies more generally with resistors replaced by impedances.

Since it's linear it only has to behave the same with **two** values of resistor attached to be identical for all possible applied voltages to the two terminals (ignoring the degenerate case where the voltage is zero for both resistor values).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're focusing too much on the single resistor. It is simply a stand-in for the two points on the load circuit that the voltage source is connected to. Consider these circuits:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpbdqa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The circuit that is comprised of V1 and V2 is equivalent to the circuit comprised of V3 alone, because they both produce the same voltage and current in R1 and R2.

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you are fine with that part, but what if R1 is replaced with something more complex?

The answer is that **nothing changes**. We could substitute a hugely complex mesh network of resistors, and some capacitors and inductors. It won't change the fact that the two circuits will maintain the same voltage between Nodes 1 & 2, as is between Nodes 3 & 4. Changing the load on two equivalent voltage sources will not change the fact that they are equivalent.

*Changing the load does not change the parameters of the voltage sources. It does change their response, but the change in response is equal if the circuits are truly equivalent.*

Answer (score 0):

Just look at both the terminals of circuit. (Input and Output). If two circuits provide same output for same input, then theoretically they are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your book is referring to Thevenin equivalent circuits, then indeed the equivalent circuits will produce the same  voltage across any arbitrary resistance placed across its terminals. However the proof of the existence of Thevenin equivalent circuits also shows that the equivalent circuit will produce the same voltage across any arbitrary circuit (including resistors, capacitors, inductors, batteries, etc.) placed across its terminals. This is true even for current and voltage sources provided that if they are controlled sources, they are not controlled by any parameter internal to the circuit for which the Thevenin equivalent has been derived. Google "Thevenin equivalent circuits" for more details.